# Turning a category into a poset

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $C$ be some category, for example $Set$. Is there a way to "mod out isomorphisms" in a way that the resulting category is a poset, i.e. a thin category and $hom(x,y) \cong hom (y,x)$ implies $x=y$? For $Sets$ this category would just consist of cardinals and $hom(x,y)$ has one element iff $x \leq y$. I am not speaking of the skeleton here.. under which circumstance is this possible.. does this procedure have a name?

Comment: It's very unclear how you want the ordering on the poset to be related to the category structure of the original category.  (Also, presumably you mean to say cardinals instead of ordinals.)

Comment: For instance, for sets there are plenty of maps $A\to B$ where $A$ is larger than $B$, but you have somehow decided to get rid of all these maps when forming your poset.  What sort of criterion would you want to use to get rid of maps like this in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can always define a preorder on the class of objects of a category. You define $A \leq B$ if there exists a morphism from $A$ to $B$. After that you can quotient by the equivalence relation defined by $A \sim B$ if $A\leq B$ and $B \leq A$ to obtain a partially ordered class.

However I doubt that is what you have in mind (since if do this to the category of sets you end up with a two element poset isomorphic to $\{0,1\}$ with $0\leq 0$, $0\leq 1$ and $1\leq 1$). Perhaps what you have in mind is the following. Given a category $\mathbb C$ take the sub-category $\tilde {\mathbb C}$ of $\mathbb C$ with objects the same, but with morphisms monomorphisms. Now preform the operation described in the previous paragraph. The Cantor–Bernstein theorem means that for $\mathbb{C}$ the category of sets, we have $A \sim B$ if and only if $A$ is isomorphic to $C$.

Comment: this is very close to what I need, but ultimately I want to do it for the category of finitely generated abelian groups, s.t. I end up with objects being ordered summands of $\mathbb{Z}$'s and primary cyclic groups and subgroup inclusions.. I'm not sure if Cantor-Bernstein holds for finitely generated abelian groups, since I know that it doesn't hold for groups

Comment: I looked it up: CB holds for finitely generated abelian groups!